# Using Button and Combo Box in the Row Cells in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using WPF for building a datagrid. But my datagrid table needed data to be across horizontally.

So, I have prepared data in such a way to represent rows as columns and columns as rows.

But now I need a row with buttons and one with Combo box. Is it possible? (like below table structure)

[refer image for how my grid looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qqAA.png)

Please let me know if there is such a way.

Thanks in Advance!!

Ram

Comment: A Column is usually of same type & ColumnTemplate allows you to Style its cells. Any reason why your Row represents what a column actually should? for your case it looks like every Cell in the Grid must have 3-4 possible templates (like: TextBlock or DropDown or Button) and the TemplateSelector/DataTrigger should set relevant one by looking at some data/field in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have a full row with the button as the column defines the type of cells it will have. 
You can create a horizontal datagrid by transforming the existing data grid control.

```
<DataGrid.LayoutTransform>
    <TransformGroup>
        <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="-1" />
    </TransformGroup>
</DataGrid.LayoutTransform>

<DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}">
        <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="-1" />
                </TransformGroup>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
```

This will just have the datagrid in a horizontal manner, you will still have to style the columns for the buttons/comboboxes.

Comment: I tried this. But I'm also grouping the rows which when transposed grouping the columns. Is there a way I can group my rows when rotated?